# select query not displaying column names with records

Tags: mysql

If I execute a select query it is displaying only records not column names like as follows

```
mysql> select movie_desc from movies limit 1\G;
```

> ********************* 1. row ***************************
>   
>   If the story-writer of 'Alias Janaki' had gone to a Rajamouli or a Shekar Kammula to narrate the story, the listener could have said this after the narration: "Flashback over?

What is the problem?

Comment: When you use `limit 1`, you'll get 1 row in the result.

Comment: thats ok limit 1 display one record, but in the result column name(movie_desc) not displaying with records.

Comment: Something to do with the settings of the tool you are using, perhaps? Is it only this SELECT that returns the result without the column name or do you observe the same behaviour with other SELECTs?

Comment: If i use select for other columns it displaying column names with records.

Answer (score 1):

You have an embedded carriage return ('`\r`') or another control character in your column data that is messing up your display.

This condition is easy to replicate.

First, the correct behavior:

```
mysql> USE sakila;
Database changed

mysql> select description from film limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
description: A Epic Drama of a Feminist And a Mad Scientist who must Battle a Teacher in The Canadian Rockies
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, we'll add a `\r` to the beginning of the column data:

```
mysql> select concat('\r',description) from film limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
A Epic Drama of a Feminist And a Mad Scientist who must Battle a Teacher in The Canadian Rockies
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The carriage return (ASCII 13) sends the cursor back to the left side of the screen, overwriting your column name.

```
To scrub this out, modify your query:

mysql> select REPLACE(movie_desc,'\r','') as movie_desc from movies limit 1\G;
```

This won't change what's stored, it will just remove the `\r` from the output, masking the problem.

Comment: Thanks it is working for me,but what is the reason for not displaying column name in with my above query.

Comment: It *is* being displayed but the control character is causing your terminal to print the column content at the same screen position where the column name was printed, overwriting it.